# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /register/ User has no profile for Extended User Model and Profile

Tags: python, django

When user registers the registration is done but a profile is not created and the error is thrown. In the database the user is created but without a profile. the error is highlighted at
"p_reg_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=credentials.profile)"
The bellow are the .py files for the project.
This code use to work but has suddenly stopped.
models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """

    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        "username",
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text="Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.",
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={"unique": "A user with that username already exists.", },
    )

    first_name = models.CharField("first name", max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField("last name", max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField("email", blank=True, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        "staff status",
        default=False,
        help_text=["Designates whether the user can log into this admin site."],
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        "active",
        default=True,
        help_text=(
            "Designates whether this user should be treated as active. "
            "Unselect this instead of deleting accounts."
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField("date joined", default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "user"
        verbose_name_plural = "users"

    def clean(self):
        """Try and find the new way to right this save"""
        super(User, self).save()
        self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Return the short name for the user."""
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """Send an email to this user."""
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)


class Profile(models.Model):
    """Profile class lists the library and choices and settings for each field in the model the Profile
    and also sets the database structure"""

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_pics")
    date_birth = models.DateField(max_length=75, null=True, name="date_birth")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Definition for the absolute path to be rendered in the profile-detail view"""
        # return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
        return reverse("profile-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})


class Profile1(models.Model):
    """This class lists the library classes and settings in the model"""

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile_pics")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Definition for the absolute path to be rendered in the profile-detail view"""
        # return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
        return reverse("profile-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

views.py:

```
def register(request):
    """This function provides the logic and condition for saving the classes, the form variables used
         plus the message and the redirection or rendering url """
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        p_reg_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and p_reg_form.is_valid():
            credentials = form.save()
            credentials.user = request.user
            p_reg_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=credentials.profile)
            p_reg_form.full_clean()
            p_reg_form.save()
            credentials.is_active = False
            credentials.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            email_subject = "Activate Your Account"
            message = render_to_string(
                "users/activate_account.html",
                {
                    "user": credentials,
                    "domain": current_site.domain,
                    "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(credentials.pk)),
                    "token": account_activation_token.make_token(credentials),
                },
            )
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            email = EmailMessage(email_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()
            messages.success(
                request,
                f"Account successfully created for: {first_name} {last_name} , "
                f"Please verify your email: {to_email} for access to your account",
            )
            # return HttpResponse('We have sent you an email,
            # please confirm your email address to complete registration')
            return TemplateResponse(
                request, "users/register_email_sent_confirmation.html"
            )
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        p_reg_form = ProfileRegisterForm()
    context = {"form": form, "p_reg_form": p_reg_form}
    return render(request, "users/register.html", context)
```

forms.py :

```
BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES = [x for x in range(1909, 2021)]


class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """This class lists the model and fields for the User model Registration Form"""

    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        """The model called and the field/s to be filled by the form for rendering"""

        model = User
        fields = [
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "username",
            "password1",
            "password2",
        ]
        widgets = {"country": CountrySelectWidget()}

    def clean_email(self):
        """This definition checks to see if any users already exist with this email."""
        # Get the email
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")

        # Check to see if any users already exist with this email.
        try:
            match = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Unable to find a user, this is fine
            return email

            # A user was found with this as a username, raise an error.
        raise forms.ValidationError(f"This email ({email}) address is already in use.")


class ProfileRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """This class lists the model and fields for the User model Profile Registration Form"""

    date_birth = forms.DateField(
        label="Date of birth",
        initial=datetime.date.today,
        widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES),
    )

    class Meta:
        """The model called and the field/s to be filled by the form for rendering"""

        model = Profile
        fields = ["date_birth",]
```

signals.py :

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(instance, created):
    """This function lists the model to be created and saved for the classes relating to
    other apps withing the project"""
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        Profile1.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(instance):
    """This function lists the model to be created and saved for the classes relating to
    other apps withing the project"""
    instance.profile.save()
    instance.profile1.save()
```

settings.py :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"
```

error :

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /register/
User has no profile.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:5000/register/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
User has no profile.
```

The code worked previous and only started failing fairly recently, and advice would be grateful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Whichever answer worked, it will be helpful if you could accept the answer

Comment: Your answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from

```
p_reg_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=credentials.profile)
```

At this stage, your credentials do not have profile, therefore, the error.

Try to replace:

```
            p_reg_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=credentials.profile)
            p_reg_form.full_clean()
            p_reg_form.save()
```

with something like: you probably need to tweak a bit

```
profile = p_reg_form.save()
profile.user = request.user
p_reg_form.full_clean()
p_reg_form.save()
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, the error was indeed in the code in the register method in the views.py.```        if form.is_valid() and p_reg_form.is_valid():
            credentials = form.save()
            credentials.user = request.user
            p_reg_form.full_clean()
            p_reg_form.save(commit=False)
            credentials.is_active = False
            credentials.save()
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")```

Answer (score 0):

The DoesNotExist exception is raised when an object is not found for the given parameters of a query. Django provides a DoesNotExist exception as an attribute of each model class to identify the class of object that could not be found and to allow you to catch a particular model class with try / except .